# postfix virtual_mailbox_maps causes Relay Access Denied

Tags: postfix

I have postfix 3.0.3 running with PostgreSQL 9.4. My main.cf is here:

```
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
inet_protocols = ipv4
local_recipient_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/deliver
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 192.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8
mynetworks_style = subnet
relay_domains = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_relay_domains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
setgid_group = maildrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /usr/local/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /usr/local/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /usr/local/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:1001
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = example.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 1001
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:1001
```

please notice, that `virtual_mailbox_domains` is set to `example.com`. Once I set it as `virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf`, I keep getting this error message

```
Dec 25 01:56:51 postfix/smtpd[11184]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lb0-f174.google.com[209.85.217.174]: 454 4.7.1 <example@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<someEmail@gmail.com> to=<example@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lb0-f174.google.com>
```

However, whenever I run `postmap -q example@example.com pgsql:/usr/local/etc/postfix/pgsql/pgsql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf`, I in any case get `example.com`

`pgsql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf` looks like this:

```
user = vmail
password = qwerty
hosts = /tmp
dbname = vmail
query = SELECT split_part(username,'@',2) FROM users WHERE username = '%s'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try `SELECT split_part(username,'@',2) FROM users WHERE split_part(username,'@',2) = '%s'`? as postfix should send the domain name instead of email address when querying `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

Comment: @clement  You are awesome, that was the solution. Please submit it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try

```
SELECT split_part(username,'@',2) FROM users WHERE split_part(username,'@',2) = '%s'?
```

as postfix should send the domain name instead of email address when querying `virtual_mailbox_domains`.

Also instead of performing `split_part` twice in every query,you can create a column for domain name and index the column for better performance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `virtual_mailbox_domains` Postfix expects a list of domains, it does not query the map (and specifically, not using a complete e-mail address). I know little of Postgres database, but I assume in your case the query should look like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT split_part(username, '@', 2) FROM users;
```

For the best performance, consider having domains in another table, separate from users.